# Ionic 3 Set date from selected date and make gap in dates

Tags: angular, ionic3

I need some help . in app i want when user select date then i need to generate next 3 date by auto . like if user select 3/8/19(3 / march / 19) so the next date look like this 
date1: 3/march/19
date2: 5/april/19 (1 month 2 days gap)
date3: 8/june/19  (2 month 3 days gap)

```
 <ion-content>
     <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Date</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime  displayFormat="DD/MMMM/YYYY" min="2010" max="2050-10-31" formControlName="birthday" > //if user example select 2/16/19
            </ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <div> 
        <h1>first vaccine</h1>
        <p> here comes the date of selected date after 2 days</p> //here come 2/18/19
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try liike this

```
    autoDate=[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                    birthday: [this.firstName],
                    lastName: [this.lastName]
                });
            this.newdate();         // call function like this
        }    

    newdate(){
     //subscribe your input formcontrol for value change
      this.myForm.controls['birthday'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {

// birthday date can be acessed by value variable
            var day = new Date('2/16/19'); //static date from caluclation example
            var nextDay = new Date(day);
            nextDay.setDate(day.getDate()+2);
            autodate['first']=nextDay;
    //      calculate your next three date here
         console.log(value);
      });
    }
```

In HTML get date from **autodate**